# Why unset is not working for reference variable

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to format the below `$items` array:

```
$items = [
    [
        'key' => '1',
        'id' => 'a'
    ],
    [
        'key' => '2',
        'id' => 'b'
    ]
];
```

To

```
$items = [
    'a' => [
        'key' => '1',
        'id' => 'a'
    ],
    'b' => [
        'key' => '2',
        'id' => 'b'
    ]
];
```

with the below code:

```
foreach($items as &$item){
    $items[$item['id']] = $item;
    unset($item);
}
print_r($items);
```

But it results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1
            [id] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => 2
            [id] => b
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1
            [id] => a
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [key] => 2
            [id] => b
        )

)
```

I expected it to unset `[0]` and `[1]` elements.
Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding?

Thank you.

Comment: You should create a new array. Adding new entries to an array that is being traversed should be avoided.

Comment: @Olivier, thanks. Noted, I would create a new array in my original implementation. But I would also like to understand the issue here why the code is not unsetting the variable.

Comment: Altering the array you are iterating over is bad., because with adding new ones you will iterate over them as well. Better create a new array. But just to prove it works, please don't: https://3v4l.org/mBTFG You can reach your goal with a single liner `array_combine(array_column($items, 'id'), $items);`.

Comment: Unsetting a reference doesn't unset the original variable. `$a = 1; $b = &$a; unset($b); echo $a;`  prints `1`.

Comment: @Olivier, thanks, I found the related PHP doc detailing it.